# Is there good doctrine documentation?

Tags: php, doctrine

Is there good doctrine documentation? Which I can write regular SQL buildings.
Seeing the official example:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

```
$qb->select('u')
   ->from('User', 'u')
   ->where('u.id = ?1')
   ->orderBy('u.name', 'ASC');
```

and

```
$qb->select('u')
   ->from('User u')
   ->where('u.id = ?1')
   ->orderBy('u.name ASC');
   ->setParameter(1, 100);
```

this one has two errors. The `from()` is not compatible to itself, it accepts 2 parameters...

Answer (score 0):

You are able to write regular SQL in Doctrine but as it uses ORM you should try not to use this.

Documentation for SQL in Doctine:
[Native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)

With Doctrine you are going to query for objects, to do this you can use DQL which is simular to SQL except that is queries for objects instead of rows.

Documentation for DQL can be found here:
[DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Concerning the queryBuilder:

That is the best documentation you are going to find, yet they made a mistake just change the `from('User u')` to `from('User','u')` if it gives you errors

Comment: Actually, you are able to write a regular SQL query with Doctrine and map the result into objects ([native SQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)). But that's just a "trick" for a special cases.

Comment: Thanks for your comment I forgot about that.